# Is it possible to have tests without mocking Picasso?

Tags: android, mockito, picasso

I have a method where 
`mPicasso.load(uri).into(imageView);`

I want to avoid having mocks as much as possible and if it possible to have fake classes . 
I am wondering is there any way to test the method without using  Picasso mocks?

Comment: depends on what you want to test and what the method is doing. you shouldn't be testing third party libraries or android libraries either way, we assume they work and the people responsible for making them have ensured that

Comment: I want to be sure that load method is called ,I don't want to test how Picasso is working, just if the method is called or not

Comment: you'd have to use mockito to mock out picasso and then verify that it was called

Comment: I know about that solution ,but I want to know if it possible to solve it without mockito ? I don't want to use any mock library

Comment: why would you not want to use a mock library ?